# Красивый вывод числа с пробелами

Tags: java, числа

На вход идёт строка "123456" с типом int. Как преобразовать её в "123 456"?

Comment: Всмысле как так строка с типом int?

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(1234567).replaceAll(","," ")
```

Comment: А где в "строке" которую написал автор Вы нашли "," ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format("%,d",123456);

Вывод: 123 456
```

Любые целые числа с этим указанием будут выведены в американском варианте

Comment: Решение конкретной задачи, как вариант.  Но что если это не требование выводить в аммериканском варианте?Но что Вас натолкнуло на мысль что именно этот вариант подразумевал автор, если он не указал что именно аммериканский вариант ему нужен? Может ему завтра нужно будет выводить стринг с пробелом в иной позиции потому что будут другие тенденции в моде?